# (?)の 雑誌ですか。日本の 雑誌です。 (?)no zasshi desu ka. nihon no zasshi desu

Tags: grammar

Is どこ or 何 the right question word in this exercise or are both possible? I think どこ means "where", so the question would be "where is the magazine from? It's a magazine from Japan/a japanese magazine." Or is it also be right with "何" which means "what kind of'm

Comment: Related:  [Difference between 何の～ and どんな～](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9342/78).

Answer (score 2):

I would think you'd ask どこの国の雑誌ですか。

If you asked なんの雑誌ですか, I'd understand you be to be asking about what sort of content the magazine typically covered or its title.

Per the comments, you could ask either どこの国の雑誌 or どこの雑誌ですか.

Perhaps I'm reading too much into these different questions.  I'm not a native speaker of Japanese.  But, I imagine these questions are not too different from how they'd be similarly understood in English.

Comment: You are correct about なんの雑誌 but なんの国 is unidiomatic. I would say either どの国の〜 or simply どこの〜 unless I need to be specific that I'm asking for a country.

Comment: I would say どこの国.