# どうしますか versus 何をしますか

Tags: grammar

When do we have to use the following questions?

> どうしますか

and

> 何をしますか

Is there any difference between them?

Comment: Some context might be helpful here.

Comment: See http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/8313/what-does-%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F-mean-and-how-does-it-differ-from-%E4%BD%95%E3%82%92%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F and http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15156/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B-vs-%E4%BD%95%E3%82%92%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B?lq=1. Both should answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

「どうしますか」 could be used when it seems like something is wrong or hard to decide, like "Would this be okay?" or "What should we do?" or "What would you do if you were in my shoes?" or "What would you like to do about it?" or "How would ____ be?"

「何をしますか」 could be used for casual situations, like "What do you want to do?" or "What're you going to do?"

Comment: I received a downvote. I'd love to know if there is any misinformation in my answer.