# How do 何 and どう change the meaning of these sentences?

Tags: syntax, phrases

I know people say not to rely too much on music to learn Japanese, but I love Japanese music. Usually I try to translate the lyrics into English as I listen, but I keep hearing the phrase どうしようか and I can't really figure out what it means. Usually 何しようか usually means 'what should (I/we) do,' so I thought maybe it means 'how should (I/we) do it' or something along those lines. How does どう change the meaning of the sentence?

Note: the sentence doesn't have any comprehensive context, so I only included the singular phrase I was confused with.

Comment: This might answer your question: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/8313/what-does-%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F-mean-and-how-does-it-differ-from-%E4%BD%95%E3%82%92%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F